# Centrally stored QGIS print templates

Tags: qgis, print-composer, print-templates, composer-manager

In my organisation we would like to have a set of organisation configured print templates. It would be convinient to stores these at some central location so we only have one copy of the templates.

We could ask our users to navigate to the central location and manually add each template. 
We could also deploy the templates into the *composer_templates* folder, but this would mean a local copy for each user and this would make them more difficult to maintain.

Since we are using Windows based computers, I was wondering if it is possible to configure the QGIS Windows Registry settings to point to one or more folders and include all the found print templates in the list found in the *composer manager*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Can now](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/49a16fc898a32fe1495ce881b2f0776249f22c23) ;)

So in the next version after 2.12 you will be able to setup custom template paths in the options:

[image]

Comment: You committed that based on what the OP was asking or it was planned?

Comment: Bit of both.... ;)